# How to implement SVGs with Openlayers 7 in react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg, openlayers

I am trying to figure out, how to implement an svg file as Layer in Openlayers with react. I tried Imagelayer and Vectorlayer. The example in the docs from ol doesn`t works for my case. The svg is located below src/assets/example.svg

Anyone who can help me?

Comment: share some code

Comment: what example? Did you get it to work unmodified? What "does doesn't work for my case" mean?

Comment: Go check this example: https://mmomtchev.github.io/rlayers/#/animation